# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: kick() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, discord.py

Yeah so im new to python and im confused here this is my code

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def a(ctx):
    guild=ctx.message.guild
    for member in tuple(guild.members):
            await member.kick(member)

bot.run('hidden')
```

yea so idk why im getting an error but yea i am

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: kick() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

And I couldnt find anything on google that helped me so im posting it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can clearly see the error.

#### Error:

```
await member.kick(member)
```

You are first using `member.kick` and then passing `member` into the function again. This wouldn't show any error but just won't work. Basically, this is an syntax error which is not considered by Python. (Due to library issues)

#### Solution:

You have to change this line and do this:

```
await member.kick()
```

It doesn't need `member` inside the kick function. So it would be solved.

---

I am glad I could be of help. :)

Thank You! :D

Comment: If you are fine with it, please accept this answer by clicking on the tick below the rating option. :D